# Make consistent syntax highlighting of LaTeX source blocks

Tags: latex, org-babel, font-lock

Org manual's solution for syntax highlighting of org-babel code blocks is to turn on native fontification with

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

works well for LaTeX code enclosed in blocks with

```
#+BEGIN_SRC latex
```

but not for blocks with:

```
#+BEGIN_LATEX
```

[image: See sample image]

Is there a way to make both types of LaTeX source blocks use the same LaTeX syntax highlighting scheme/setting?

Answer (score 1):

[image: works badge]

In past I want did the same. So I found the answer by accident another day, funny.

I saw that you can do it with  any org command prefixed with #+BEGIN by just writing a babel language name after it as we use with in  `#+BEGIN_SRC` blocks. See yourself:

[image: cancer]